List available packages with their summaries
To get summaries of installed packages, rpm can be used.
How can be obtained a listing that includes summaries of available packages or updates?

Hi! What research into this have you done so far? This feels like you never tried to do an update, which you should research and try.

maybe a too fast downvote for this self answer question ?

Turns out that this can be achieved with dnf:
dnf repoquery --available --qf "%{NAME}\t%{SUMMARY}"

Notice that dnf does not need \n at the end because it knows to insert line delimiters.
